# How add parameter in project -stage.yaml for Swarm on docker

Tags: docker, parameters, project, swarm

I am using Swarm with Docker and i want to change default upload size. But i don't how to add this parameter in **project-stage.yaml**.

I tried like this :

```
swarm:
      swarm.undertow.servers.default-server.http-listeners.default.max-post-size:52428800
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: resolved: must be adde like :swarm:
  undertow:
    servers:
        default-server:
            http-listeners:
                default:
                  max-post-size : 550000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should format your yaml like this:

```
undertow:
  servers:
    default-server:
      http-listeners:
        default:
          max-post-size: 52428800
```